# Mercurial branch using clone - how to share

Tags: mercurial, repository, branch, clone

I would like to know how is it supposed to do the following in mercurial.

My repository is on our server where mercurial-server is running. I develop on Windows and because my project is supposed to be multiplatform, I've set up Jenkins build server which builds using a Linux slave machine automatically after each push.

Now what I need:
Quite often the build on Linux does not work, because I'm using "treat warnings as errors" and gcc gives different warnings than MSVC. Then I need to fix the build and I don't want to mess the repository with "fixing" commits (often more commits are needed to fix all gcc warnings). It would be ok for me to have a single commit in the repo for a fix of the linux build.

I thought I could just clone the repository to a 'fixing repo' (like a branch using clone) and do as many fixing commits as needed. Then just merge all these commits to the main repo as a single fixing commit. But then I need to make my 'fixing repo' public (i.e. clone the fixing repo to the remote server) to allow jenkins to build the sources. But how to get rid of the 'fixing repo' when the fix is finished? It is probably not a good idea to allow users delete remote repositories, is it?

Possibilities I see:
1) forgot about branching using clone, do a named branch, fix, merge to master branch and close the fixing branch - **probably not a common solution in mercurial to create a named branch for this**
2) just create a new head (possibly set a bookmark), fix, merge to master head (branch) and close the fixing head (can I close a head?) - **better but I still have to do with all fixing commits in the main repository**
3) using the cloned 'fixing repo', set up ssh access or even mercurial-server for Jenkins to my personal machine and let it clone from it, build and when the build is fixed, just merge all commit from local 'fixing repo' to remote repository as a single commit

Some better solution? Or do I want to do something unusual?
Thanks.

Comment: Why you want delete your local clone after bug-fix? It's not a last bug, you'll re-clone "main" repo again and again

Comment: Is it OK for you to push your WIP to "main" for Jenkins?

Comment: @LazyBadger This is exactly the reason for cloning on remote, I want to provide my WIP to Jenkins, but not using "main" repo.

Comment: Anyway it's true that I could just use the same remote repo for every bug fix

Comment: Can you (or Jenkins-admin) add new target for Jenkins? Can you have ssh:// access to repo-server?

Comment: Yes, I can create targets for Jenkins, but I don't have ssh shell access to repo-server (so I cannot delete/rename remote repo). I only have access via hg user which has ssh shell forbidden.